# Dereferencing pointer to imcomplete type in linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, pointers, kernel, system-calls

So I'm trying to make a new system call in Red Hat 2.4.20 for a project that I've been working on. And for the I've created a C file to try the system call works or not and I've been getting the same error, Dereferencing pointer to imcomplete type, for days. My header file is here:

```
    struct prcdata {
long counter; /* process counter value */
long nice; /* process nice value */
long prio; /* calculated with 20- processes’ nice value */
long weight; /* calculated with 20-nice+counter */
pid_t pid; /* process id */
long uid; /* user id of process owner */
int nofprocess; /* number of process of owner of current process
*/}
;
```

My C file for the system call is like this

```
#include <linux/mysyscall.h>
asmlinkage int cprocinf(struct prcdata *data)
{
    cli();
    struct prcdata temp;
    copy_from_user(&temp,data,sizeof(struct prcdata));
    temp.prio=20-current->nice;
    temp.weight=current->counter + temp.prio;
    temp.rank=2*current->nice;
    temp.pid=current->pid;
    temp.uid=current->uid;
    temp.processcount=current->user->proccesses.counter;
    copy_to_user(data,&temp,sizeof(struct prcdata));
    return 0;
    sti();

}
```

And the file to try this code is like this

```
#include <linux/mysyscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
int ret;
struct prcdata *data; 
ret=mysyscall(data);
printf("First values of process\n");
printf("Nice Value. %d\nPriority: %d\n", -data->prio+20,data->prio);
printf("Weight: %d\n", data->weight);
printf("Rank: %d\nPid: %d\nPid: %d\nParent: %d\nProcess Count: %d\n",data->rank,data->pid,data->pidparent,data->processcount);
}
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: You are passing an unintialized pointer to `mysycall`. And where is `arg1` defined?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
copy_from_user(&temp,arg1,sizeof(struct prcdata));
....
copy_to_user(arg1,&temp,sizeof(struct prcdata));
```

should be

```
copy_from_user(&temp,data,sizeof(struct prcdata));
....
copy_to_user(data,&temp,sizeof(struct prcdata));
```

And here you need to initialize the pointer or pass a local object:

```
main()
{
    int ret;
    struct prcdata data; 
    ret=mysyscall(&data);
    ...
}
```

or

```
main()
{
    int ret;
    struct prcdata *data = malloc(sizeof (struct prcdata));
    ret=mysyscall(&data);
    ...
    free(data);
}
```